# Разметка дисков. Debian

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian

Я решил установить Debian на свой ноутбук (Dell Inspirion 15 3000 Series).
Во время установки у меня возникла ошибка при установке `grub` и было выведено следующее сообщение: Вам придется загружать ядро `/vmlinuz` вручную с раздела `/dev/sda5` и передать ему в качестве аргумента `root=/dev/sda5 quiet`.

Думаю, это произошло из-за неправильной разметки дисков. При установке я выбрал автоматическую разметку, используя наибольшее свободное пространств, в следствие чего создалось 2 логических раздела. Первый: `ext4 236.3 GB`, второй: `подк 4.2 GB`. Ни на каком из дисков не стояла метка `Загрузочный`. Более того, когда я закончил разметку, мне вышло сообщение, что не найдено разделов `EFI`.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как нужно разметить диски? Включая то, какие метки у них нужно ставить и сколько рекомендуется памяти на них выделять.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если ставитесь с флешки, то, возможно, при всех правильных действиях возникает конфликт, описанный в [мануале](https://www.debian.org/releases/wheezy/debian-installer/index.ru.html).

Но чаще всего Дебиан запутывается, действительно, в отсутствие первичного раздела с меткой загрузки. Так что рекомендовал бы создать первичный (primary) раздел под /boot (sda1) с установленным флагом загрузки, размером 200-250 мегабайт и файловой системой ext2, смонтированной в режиме sync (впрочем, ext2 здесь не догма; сойдёт и ext4, и xfs). Кроме него понадобится ещё минимум два раздела: swap по размеру RAM и / (xfs) на всё остальное место. Это простейший из вариантов, при дальнейших установках можно будет попробовать что-нибудь более сложное. Например, отдельный /tmp с ext2 или tmpfs; отдельный /home, смонтированный с nosuid или даже noexec и/или с usr-/qrpquota; и т.д. и т.д.

Note: вышеописанное в части про /boot — не про EFI!

Comment: Что можно делать при ошибке: `не удалось смонтировать файловую систему типа vfat на устройстве SCIS5 (0,0,0), раздел #4 (sdb) в точке /boot/efi.`?

Answer (score 0):

Моя конфигурация в режиме EFI. Установка с USB носителя.

```
512mb      EPS    EFI
512mb      ext2   /boot первичный
16386mb    swap   (по размеру оперативки)
остаток    btrfs  /
```

Все завелось. Тоже сидел тыкал минут 40 с ошибкой монтирования vfat для /boot/efi